# How do I stop a stuck-and-running cron job (Elysia Cron on Pantheon)?

Tags: cron

One of my cron jobs, which are all managed by [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) and running in its default channel, is stuck and running (R).  My site is hosted by Pantheon, in case that matters.

The job in question is schedule to execute at 15 minute intervals.

What do you recommend I do to stop the stuck-and-running job?

Answer (score 10):

```
 update elysia_cron set running = 0 where name = '[THE NAME IF YOUR CRON JOB]';
```

Actual sql query based on Mika A answer above

Answer (score 4):

I think if the job is stuck somewhere, you may not have direct access to the process to stop it. What you can do is just set the *running* value to 0 in the *{elysia_cron}* table for the corresponding job.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, the instruction given by @t14

```
update elysia_cron set running = 0 where name = '[THE NAME IF YOUR CRON JOB]';
```

should be given directly in MySQL (command line or phpMyAdmin whatsoever).
With Drush it failed to update the table